# What is the best way to create an html test report using SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, mstest, specflow

I am running tdd reports in Visual Studio 2015.

From what I have read I should be able to generate an html report with the specflow command line tool

```
specflow.exe mstestexecutionreport "Visual Studio 2015\Projects\blahSpec.csproj" /out:MyResult.html
```

This in turn complains that it cannot find a .trx type file.

```
NConsoler.NConsolerException: Could not find file 'C:\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\blahSpec\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TestResult.trx'.
```

This led me to believe that I need to set MsTest to generate a .trx file when I run the tests.  The documentation I read was not specific to what I wanted to test (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7577a33c-84bc-4144-b45f-76c8e03b0a8e/create-a-trx-file-whenever-any-tests-are-executed-from-test-explorer?forum=vsunittest) 
It spoke of a settings file that I could not find, and I couldn't find any info on how to create one.

This foray in to the tall weeds made me feel that I was going about it the wrong way, and should get help here.

Meanwhile in Ruby...

SpecFlow's ruby equivalent: Cucumber, has a format flag that allows users to generate output into a nice HTML format that can be presented to higher ups.

```
cucumber --format html -o blah.html
```

What is the best way to do this in VS2015?  Am I close or am I going about it the wrong way?

I am using
Specflow and Selenium Webdriver

Comment: I amended my question to cover your requests.  If you need anymore information, I'd be happy to supply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for those who employ SpecFlow and Selenium to test their web based application and want the report formatted in an HTML format

1. Navigate to ..\Projects[project name]..\bin\Debug
2. run MSTEST to generate a .trx file

   `mstest /testcontainer:[projectname].dll /ResultsFile:TestResult.trx`
3. lastly from ..[project name]\packages\SpecFlow.[version number]\tools,  run the SpecFlow command line tool to grab the .trx file and generate the report.

   `specflow.exe mstestexecutionreport "C:\Users\blah\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" /out:MyResult.html /testresult:TestResult.trx`
4. View file and celebrate